# A "different" third isomorphism theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

I know that, given $H, K \unlhd G$ and $K \leq H$, one has
$$\frac{G/K}{H/K} \simeq \frac{G}{H} \, .$$
Under the same hypotheses, is it true that
$$\frac{G/K}{G/H} \simeq \frac{H}{K} \quad \huge{?}$$

I think it's wrong, but I can't find a counterexample. If it's true can you deduce it from the previous statement or vice versa?

Comment: What does the left side even mean? $G/H$ is not a subgroup of $G/K$.

Comment: Your question is a touch unclear: certainly under the first hypotheses, it _follows_ that $K$ is normal in $H$. So you don't need to _add_ that hypothesis, if you keep the first. On another hand, $K$ normal in $H$ and $H$ normal in $G$ does not imply that $K$ is normal in $G$. The more genuine problem is that I don't see a map $G/H\to G/K$...

Comment: Forget about the third isomorphism theorem. What yuou are really saying is, if $G/K\cong H$, is $G/H\cong K$? This is true for numbers, but quotients aren't subgroups in general, so the question ends up not being well defined.

Comment: @paulgarrett I corrected the question, sorry one property was redundant. As many pointed out, my question isn't well defined. When I asked the question my biggest concern was "is G/H normal in G/K?" but I assumed it was a subset, that really isn't in general... I found a very simple "example" (I hope it's correct) to show this, let $<6>=K,<2>=H \unlhd\mathbb{Z}=G$, then $K\leq H$ but $G/K=\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}, G/H=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $G/H \not \subseteq G/K$, so the quotient I wrote doesn't make sense!

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can say is that there is a surjective map $G/K\to G/H$ whose kernel is $H/K$. So instead of cokernels you take kernels.

Comment: Right! That's the direction the natural map goes. :)